# How to instruct these simple modules to run in sequence?

Tags: python, module

I have an assignment where I need to create three modules to be called and run, in sequence, within a main program. I assume this is a test case for the more complex final project, but I know it sounds like a dumb idea, so I am including the instructions.  I have the code for each of 3 individual modules here (Please note: All of this would work just fine as a single script, but I am tasked with splitting it up).

Instructions:

> Draw the hierarchy chart and then plan the logic for a program that calculates a person’s body mass index (BMI). BMI is a statistical measure that compares a person’s weight and height. The program uses three modules. The first prompts a user for and accepts the user’s height in inches. The second module accepts the user’s weight in pounds and converts the user’s height to meters and weight to kilograms. Then, it calculates BMI as weight in kilograms divided by height in meters squared, and displays the results. There are 2.54 centimeters in an inch, 100 centimeters in a meter, 453.59 grams in a pound, and 1,000 grams in a kilogram. Use named constants whenever you think they are appropriate. The last module displays the message End of job.   Create the program in Python and provide the link to repl.it or attach the .py file.

Note that running bmi_main.py actually DOES proceed to launch the three modules in sequence, but there is an error from module 2 because it uses 'height' which is a variable defined in module 1 that is apparently forgotten when module 2 starts. This implies I need height to be a global variable even though it is being defined by the user. I didn't think that would be a problem, but trying to declare height at the top of the main program is giving me errors. How can I fix this while retaining this (questionable but necessary) structure?

Main:

```
#Title: BMI Main
#Author: Name
#Class: CISPROG01

import bmi_mod01.py;
import bmi_mod02.py;
import bmi_mod03.py;

#This is the main program, which has to call the modules to carry out entire
#procedures in sequence. I really hope that can be done but I am worried because
#I have not seen a single example online where that has been accomplished.
```

Module 01:

```
#Title: BMI Mod01
#Author: Name
#Class: CISPROG01

print("This program will calculate your BMI. \n"
      "Please enter your height in inches.");
height = int(input());
print("Your height is " + str(height) + " inches.");
```

Module 02:

```
#Title: BMI Mod02
#Author: Name
#Class: CISPROG01

print("Please enter your weight in lbs.")
weight = int(input());
print("Your weight is " + str(weight) + " lbs. \n \n");
inch_to_m = float(2.54*height/100);
lbs_to_kg = float(weight*453.59/1000);
BMI = float((lbs_to_kg)/((inch_to_m)**2));
print("Your BMI is " + str(BMI) + " kg/m^2.");
```

Module 03:

```
#Title: BMI Mod03
#Author: Name
#Class: CISPROG01

print("End of job.");
```

Comment: I am curious as to whether you tried running this code. By calling `import` python is processing that file, and thus "running" it. The error I see you would encounter is that when you call import you leave out the extension py. So instead of `import bmi_mod01.py` it would just be `import bmi_mod01`. Also, in regards to your second question typically if you wanted to iterate your program and return you would do just that, return using a function or create a loop. You would not execute the file again (you should only call import once).

Comment: Thank you for responding. I am updating my question. I had syntax errors and mislabeled a variable. Not typing '.py' doesn't seem to matter at all. In fact, all the programs ARE running in sequence when I run bmi_main.py. *The problem, I think, is that 'height' is a variable local to module 2 but I need to use it in module 3, so it needs to be global. How do I do that? I've tried initializing it in 'main' but it's giving me definition errors. Doing 'global height;' in module 2 does nothing.

Comment: *I meant local to module 1 but is used in module 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you call the scripts in order you can then import the necessary variables in each script. To illustrate a test:

In main.py:

```
import mod1
import mod2
```

In mod1.py:

```
height = input()
```

In mod2.py:

```
from mod1 import height
print (height)
```

Using this you should be able to reference those variables and run that code in sequence. Hope it helps!